# Postgres Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer LINE 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm using postgres and i want tried date_diff, but i get this error

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   boolean = integer LINE 1

and then this is my query

```
select id_mitra
      ,company_name 
from ref_mitra
where reject=0 and DATE_DIFF(now(),date_status) > 3 and active='N'
```

what wrong in my query?

Comment: Show your table description please. Maybe `reject` is a boolean.

Comment: If you want to use the value 0 (zero), you have to cast this value to a boolean: reject= CAST(0 as boolean)

Comment: You need to compare a boolean to a boolean `where reject = false`. There is also no `date_diff` function in Postgres.

Comment: @Wida try `reject=0::boolean` or `reject=false`

Comment: that table is save date, like this `2014-09-26`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your value 0 to boolean:

```
select id_mitra
      ,company_name 
from ref_mitra
where reject = CAST(0 as boolean) 
and DATE_DIFF(now(),date_status) > 3 
and active='N';
```

Or use a boolean:

```
select id_mitra
      ,company_name 
from ref_mitra
where reject = false 
and DATE_DIFF(now(),date_status) > 3 
and active='N';
```

DATE_DIFF() isn't a standard function in PostgreSQL, but maybe you created a function using this name.

Comment: Are you sure that `date_diff` is avail. in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @vivek: No I'm not, but you could create it yourself using CREATE FUNCTION

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors in your query:

1. you are comparing a number (`0`) to a `boolean`
2. there is no `date_diff()` function in Postgres

Assuming `date_status` is a (real) `date` column, your query should look like this:

```
select id_mitra
      ,company_name 
from ref_mitra
where reject = false 
  and current_date - date_status > 3 
  and active='N';
```

`now()` returns a `timestamp` but as you apparently want the number of days (not an `interval`) you should use `current_date` instead of `now()`.

I am not sure what `date_diff()` *really* does, maybe you need to write `date_status - current_date` to get the same behaviour.

Instead of `reject = false` you can also use `where not reject`

Comment: this is what I was going to answer :)

Comment: Using NOT for a boolean is a nice trick, but only when NOT isn't a query parameter: You can't use a prepared statement where NOT depends on user input.